# Where exactly are variables or identifiers stored in C++?

Tags: c++, object, variables

According to my current knowledge variables(identifiers) point to object of a particular type(int,bool,etc..) that are objects in memory. Where and how are the the variables themselves store? Are they stored with the objects they point to or are they stored in some other place?

For example;

```
int main()
{
    int a_number = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

So the variable a_number point to an int object in memory, but where is a_number itself??

If say the 2 is in a 4 byte memory, is a_number consuming a portion of it?? Or is a_number consuming some other allocated memory somewhere??

By the way I currently studying C++(am a beginner in programming) and I was considering this and couldn't really visualize it.
Thank you.

Comment: The variable name `a_number` doesn't need to exist at all after the program is compiled.  It may be part of the program for debugging purposes.

Comment: This might be instructive - the program compiles to just the return from `main`; live: https://godbolt.org/z/BMV9ln

Comment: At the low lever, variable names are just pointers to some memory, which is allocated by the compiler (automatic, heap, whatever). At the assembly level all that exists is a pointer and a size.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis  would suggest "named location(s)"  rather than _"pointers"_.  As "pointer" has a definite other meaning in the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, `a_number` names an `int` object that consumes `sizeof(int)` bytes and has automatic storage duration. Memory for storage with automatic duration is typically allocated in the stack frame of the function to which the declaration belongs (`main()` in this case).

`a_number` effectively becomes a name for the `int` object stored in these bytes. The name does not exist at runtime, because it is no longer needed at that time. The only purpose of the name is to allow you to refer to the object in code.

Comment: Can the variable `a_number` be stored in a register?  If so, it doesn't occupy any memory.

Answer (score 2):

Variables can stored in memory areas or in processor registers, depending on the compiler and optimization settings.

Let's assume that your compiler is using a *stack* for function local variables and parameters.  Your `a_number` variable would be placed on the stack since it's lifetime is temporary (will disappear after execution leaves the function).

The compiler is allowed to place the `a_number` into a processor `register`.  In this case, the variable doesn't exist in memory because processor registers are not in memory (they don't have addresses).

Since your program doesn't use the `a_number` variable after declaration, the compiler can eliminate the variable and not use memory.  There is no difference in behavior of your program with or without the variable; thus the compiler can eliminate the variable.

The location of your variable depends on your compiler.  You compiler can store variables "on the stack", in a processor register or eliminate the variable.  The location also depends on the "optimization setting" on your compiler.  Some compilers may not optimize on the lowest settings and remove the variable on the higher settings.

Comment: That's an insightful explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> but where is `a_number` itself?

Just where you see it, in the source code file.  The compiler sees it there and keeps track of it, generating what code it needs to.  If you have debugging turned on, then the symbol is stored along with the code in a special look up table so you can see it in the debugger as well.